# Redistricting for QGIS plugin,voters field error

Tags: qgis, redistricting

I'm using the Redistricting for QGIS plugin .My QGIS version is 2.14.10-Essen.I'm getting this error message:The pengundi (voters field) must be an integer number field.
[image]

My shapefile is the shp file which is given in the plugin data folder.The pengundi field type is Integer64,but I also tried with Integer type and I'm still getting the same error.

[image]
What can be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you provide some screen shots?

Comment: Hy! I added an image about my layer's properties and the error message.